# Select default value if column does not exist in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to select a default value to a column if the column does not exist in the table. Following code seems doesn't give my expected output.

```
SELECT CustomerID, (select case when exists (select *
                       from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                       where table_name = 'Customers' and
                             column_name = 'Age'
                      )
          then Age
          else 0 as Age
     end)
FROM (select * from Customers);
```

Since Age column doesn't exist in the table result should be given as:-

```
CustomerID | Age
-----------|----
Cust01     | 0
Cust02     | 0
```

Can someone suggest me a solution or the error in above code snippet.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL.  A regular `SELECT` cannot refer to a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: I wouldn't dare posting this as full answer, since I don't know Oracle much - but I believe just as in almost every DB system - the query compilation requires all objects (here: column) to exist (or be created during execution of the query). I guess dynamic SQL is your only alternative here.

Comment: Unless it's something new in 12c, there is no `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in the flagship Oracle database. Did you perhaps mean to tag this for MySQL? If so, please be aware that the `[oracle]` tag should be used only for questions which refer to Oracle's flagship database, not for other Oracle products such as Java or MySQL.

Comment: Valid observation Bob..!! Dont know why the tag is for oracle.. Cheers

Comment: Agree with Bob and Xing. No issue with the tagging since this is related to oracle. However INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  has to be replaced with USER_TAB_COLUMNS in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by experts, you need to use a Oracle PLSQL block and achieve your requirement using dynamic sql. Please see below the same code which is written keeping your requirement in mind. You can try implementing your code with this:

```
declare

var number;

var2 varchar2(4000);

type abc is record
( col1   number,
  col2   number);

type var3 is table of abc index by pls_integer;

var4 var3;


begin

select count(1) 
into var
from employee;

var2:= 'select A,  '||case when var is null then 1 else 2 end || '  from test where rownum < 10'; 


dbms_output.put_line(var2);

execute immediate var2 bulk collect into var4;

for rec in 1..var4.last
loop

dbms_output.put_line(var4(rec).col1 ||',' ||var4(rec).col2); 

end loop;

end;
```

Output:

```
select A,  2  from test where rownum < 10
1444,2
1445,2
1446,2
1447,2
1448,2
1449,2
1450,2
1451,2
1452,2
```